# MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed.

Tags: java, mysql, sql, asynchronous

So Im making a bunch of async calls, only issue is, in my prepare method which generates a PreparedStatement, it grabs the connection (or uses a new one if the connection is faulty), and for some reason still throws this error.

I initially thought (and still kind of do) that it's because majority of the use cases that call this method are called asynchronously. So I made the method synchronized (never used that keyword before, but figured it was fitting after a bit of research), and still, the method throws an error...

```
public synchronized PreparedStatement prepare(String statement) throws SQLException {
    Connection c = getConnection();
    if (c == null || c.isClosed()) return getNewConnection().prepareStatement(statement);
    Logger.debug("not null and not closed " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
    return c.prepareStatement(statement); //throws error here
}
```

How do I make it so other threads can't alter the connection until the prepare method has finished with it?

Comment: What does getConnection() do?

Comment: returns the connection currently saved in memory
it is initially initialized by getNewConnection
the connection is closed after use every time though, but when I need a connection again, I want to be able to get one... figured this should work but it just doesnt.

Comment: Where is the connection closed? Basically the problem is that your use of a single connection is only partially synchronized.

Comment: I ended up just removing the close(connection) in the method that was, well, closing the connection. Im still not sure how to sync all that up properly.. ;/

Comment: That may work, if the connection implementation you use happens to be thread safe. But once you start relying on the state of the connection (e.g. using transactions) it will no longer work correctly. The simplest solution would be for each thread to allocate a connection when it starts, pass that connection as a parameter to functions like prepare, and then close the connection when it terminates. That will make it expensive to start a thread, as it will involve opening a new connection, and you will need as many connections as you have threads, which may be too many.

Comment: So then that isn't a simple solution if it will be too many considering the number of threads? In fact it doesnt seem like a solution at all then?

Comment: That depends on how many threads you have -- a connection pool is the way to go in general

Answer (score 1):

Something like this is happening:

Thread 1: calls `prepare()`, creates a connection and returns a prepared statement and leaves `prepare()`, so other threads may now enter `prepare()`

Thread 1: starts running the query

Thread 2: enters prepare and checks that the connection is OK -- this is the same connection that thread 1 created and is using.

Thread 1: closes the connection

Thread 2: tries to call prepareStatement on the connection, which is now closed

You should investigate using a connection pool, which will give each thread its own connection, which is returned to the pool when it is 'closed'.

Comment: shouldn't synchronize stop the thread 2 from entering the method until thread 1 is finished with it?

Comment: Thread 1 doesn't run the query or close the connection in that synchronized method -- it just creates the PreparedStatement. The rest is done somewhere else, not synchronized. I've made the description clearer.